# Django / Bootstrap forms - Input size - Python

Tags: python, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning Django together with Bootstrap (5.1.3), and I'd like to keep my code as simple as possible for future updates.
That's why I went for generic views in Django (Create/Detail/Edit...). That works great, all the features work seamlessly now.

What I'm struggling with is the layout of my Edit / Create forms. I can't find a way to increase the size of the input boxes.

I have the following code, for my Model:

```
    class customer(models.Model):
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, editable = False, verbose_name = u"Créé le")
        modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, editable = False, verbose_name = u"Modifié le")
        
        fk_referrer = models.ForeignKey('customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Parrain', blank = True, null=True)
        surname = models.CharField('Prénom', max_length=200)
        lastname = models.CharField('Nom', max_length=200)
        phonenumber = PhoneNumberField('Téléphone', blank = True, null = True)
        email = models.EmailField('Email',max_length=100, blank = True, null = True)
        fk_interest = models.ManyToManyField(interests, verbose_name='Interêts', blank=True)
        comments = models.TextField('Commentaires', max_length=2000, blank=True, null = True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return (self.surname + " " + self.lastname)
```

I did create a generic view:

```
    class CustomerEditView(UpdateView):
        model = customer
        fields = "__all__"
        template_name = 'client/edition.html'
        success_url = '/client/'
```

And have added the form in edition.html template:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 
    <!-- Security token -->
    {% csrf_token %}
 
    <!-- Using the formset -->
<table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
</table>     
    <input type="submit" value="{% if object %}Mettre à jour{% else %}Créer{% endif %}">
</form>
```

Here's what the output looks like:

[Form layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utKWz.png)

The text input fields are not large enough. I would like to at least fill the table (shown with a border)
I think I should be able to sort it out using Forms, and redefining all my views to make them more specific (not generic). But is there a way to update the view / bootstrap styles so the width of the input fields would use all the space available ? Maybe using a Form on top of a generic view ?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, this is a CSS thing. Wouldn't a quick fix be to just set `width:100%` on al the inputs?

Comment: I was able to get a step further with a Form, `widgets = { 'surname': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 200})}` and `form_class = CustomerForm`
Now the html output has size="200". But still, the field is too short. IfI remove the default CSS, I have a wider field, so this seems to be a bootstrap setting. I'll be looking in that direction. I now understand the form_class, which is good for other stuff.

Comment: I was able to have the correct display by adding a css with .table input and width 100%. I hope this won't have an impact on other pages I'm creating.

Comment: If you don't want it to impact any other page i suggest you link the stylesheet to this page only. Another approach would be to include the styling directly in the page <head> or to include it in the style attribute on the HTML element itself.

Answer (score 0):

I use crispy forms with Django. They work alongside bootstrap and are very easy to use. Please check out this example.
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/28/advanced-form-rendering-with-django-crispy-forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap render the form element manually and use the bootstrap form control size class (i.e. form-control-lg) like below.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                  <!-- col-md-6 -->
                  <strong>{{ form.email.label_tag }}</strong>{{ form.email|add_class:'form-control form-control-lg' }}
                  <text class="text-danger">{{ form.email.errors }}</text>
                  {% if form.email.help_text %}
                    <small>{{ form.email.help_text|safe }}</small>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
```